# quoted text background is looking ugly?

Tags: discussion

Earlier the quoted part background color was light orangish color, now the color is changed and looking somewhat ugly to me, at least comparing previous one. Is this new design change?

A reference screenshot of new quoted background:

[image]

I don't have old design for reference. But if someone have, please add for reference.

[image]

Comment: Some already complained about the change on MSE: [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow).

Comment: @sv. Interesting! And I thought I am the only one find this ugly.

Comment: Extended discussion here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345323/196352

Comment: @Mr_Green Related [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/260388)

Comment: Even the previous yellow background looks like scripture's color to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the design has been changed. Visit
following MSE post for more information:

### [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/260388)

Tip: Occasionally refer [**Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/260388) to trace these type of changes.

Comment: Btw, I am thinking if we, Hinduism Stack Exchange can have different design for block quotes. E.g background should be looking like ancient sacred scripture book page.

Comment: that would be great! Should I make this post as feature request and add this whatever you said?

Comment: @Pandya But why is this change considered as an improvement? Previously it was easy to differentiate between our own texts and the blockquotes but that is now hardly possible.

Comment: @Rickross You need to reply MSE question I linked so-that developers can be notified.

Comment: Ideally one needs to do that but I don't think they are going to alter it back to what it was .. right now, it's not looking good .. it's not differentiating our own texts from the block quotes @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross [Can the sites about religions have suitable background for block quotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345323/260388)

Comment: Yes, may be a good idea. At least the yellow one should be brought back. @Pandya