# Request for increasing the moderator's count

Tags: support, feature-request, moderators

There are three excellent moderators for the main site. There is no doubt about it.

As mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/should-we-elect-new-moderators) question, the moderators may be slightly busy and we can observe some delay in moderating, especially in making decisions of (important) answering *policies*. This causes harm to the main site since some users may have some hidden agenda, which we can clearly understand from their answers.

Above all the rules, there should be a common sense in answering the questions. Pushing the pressure points based on the hidden agenda has to be taken care by moderators. Else the debate may not end and the main site may not be in correct orientation.

So I am requesting the corresponding authorities to increase the moderators as soon as possible.

Comment: Related or dupe: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/647

Comment: This causes harm to the main site since some users may have some hidden agenda, which we can clearly understand from their answers. --- Spot on .. right now if we read certain answers on site, we will get the feel that we are on "what sceptics, atheists think about Hinduism".SE and not on Hinduism.SE.

Comment: Unless we get all the Mods actively participating this site is a complete mess . Another problem is a lot of the avid users are also not active too these days and that is being used by these agenda driven users to the full advantage whose only motive is to demean Hinduism. Then they can do it on Sceptics, this is not the right place to do it.This is about learning about Hinduism. Off late they have been crossing all limits in answers and in doing so quoting just about anybody.

Comment: "This causes harm to the main site since some users may have some hidden agenda, which we can clearly understand from their answers." - you're right, we should delete answers like [these](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37985/2995) solely based on scientific journals. Where are the mods? Why are they not deleting this answer which has nothing to do with Hinduism?

Comment: @sv, i actually agree with deleting those answers you linked, despite your sarcasm - because they don't really quote scriptures, just news articles and modernized gurus.

Comment: I think our best hope is to get the current Mods active again particularly Destroyer and Pandya. Appointing new mods is not the right choice IMO because there are no deserved candidates right now. It will create more problems.

Comment: Is Swami Vishwananda, the one mentioned in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24716/what-is-paramahamsa-vishwanandas-stance-on-homosexuality/24717#24717,  one of HSE members ? I thought i had seen a member by that name

Comment: No, [that Vishwananda](https://mobile.twitter.com/vishwananda) is different from [the HSE user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/882/swami-vishwananda) who appears to be a follower of Vivekananda/Ramakrishna. @Carmensandiego